# In Javascript, Is there a method to trigger a function based on a live input from the mic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to create a website in which there is a animated tree. This tree sheds its leaves when someone blows air to it.
In more concrete terms, I want to trigger the shedding leaves animation after the mic gets some kind of audio input. I have no clue how this happens. Can anyone suggest me some beginner tutorials for this?

I have asked around and I am told that I must use "Web Audio API" for this but this is also very vague to comprehend.

Basically, I want to know how I should accept the live Mic Audio and then make Javascript understand that once there is a audio coming from the mic, It should trigger the shedding leaves animation.

There is one more short coming which I have concerns about: The mic audio shall catch all the audio coming to it. Say, I am using the keyboard, even the noise from the keyboard shall be treated as a audio input. I want it to specifically filter all this noise and just treat the blowing air as a trigger. Something like, Only if the audio input is above this amplitude, It must start the animation.

Please note, I am a extreme novice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stupid little thing I did on JS Bin a while ago that might give you some ideas.

http://jsbin.com/uCalijA/2/edit

The stuff you might be interested in occurs in the first 15 lines of the `draw` function. Basically, this uses an `AnalyserNode` to get the time domain data and uses it to calculate the amplitude. The `ratio` variable then converts that to a slightly easier-to-work-with value on the scale of 0-100, with 0 being silence.

You should be able to tweak that and to something to the effect of

```
if ( ratio > threshold  ) {
  blowLeaves();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web Audio API is a part of HTML5 stack hance you may not find many examples at this point of time. I my self has not used Web Audio API, but had the following artical bookmarked. I hope it would help you in your quest

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Cheers